# Какой есть аналог сравнения нескольких значений справа от оператора IN в Oracle?

Tags: sql, sql-server

В Oracle можно написать такой запрос:

```
select * from t where (t.x, t.y) in (select x, y from t2);
```

Какой есть аналог в SQL-Сервер?

Comment: Возможно вы не правильно ищете. То, о чём вы спрашиваете, это разница в SQL диалектах. Оно ни к PL/SQL, ни к T-SQL, не относится.

Answer (score 2):

```
select t.*
  from t
  join (select x, y from t2) x on t.x=x.x and t.y=x.y
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select t.*
    from t
    where exists (select null from t2 where t2.x = t.x and t2.y = t.y)
```

В некоторых случаях производительность лучше, чем с помощью `join`